# Xcode 4.2: Error 0xC002 when trying to use a jailbroken iPhone 3G for development

Tags: xcode4, ios5, jailbreak

I have this jailbroken iPhone 3G with iOS version 4.2.1 (the latest supported version). When I connect it to Xcode 4.2, Xcode starts copying the debug symbols. It stops copying towards the end of the process, and shows the following error:

```
Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC002)
No such file or directory, at ‘/SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-867/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit_Utilities.m:864’
```

Anybody experiencing anything similar?

I know I should try and restore the phone, but I'm asking just in case anybody can come up with a solution that doesn't involve restoring it.

In [this post on mactechnews.de](http://www.mactechnews.de/forum/thread/Xcode-4-2-Fehlermeldung-%5DXcode-has-encountered-an-unexpected-error-%280xC002%29-302998.html), one guy reports the same problem -- with no solution, so far.

Comment: i'm also have the same problem. :( i'm running test builds via testflightapp.com on that device. but it still disallows me to debug app.

Comment: If your interested in this question why not support the Area 51 proposal for a [jail-breaking Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=EuWVi6IpN0_KzzEhC7I-Qw2)

Comment: definitely experiencing this issue, my guess is that it's an attempt to deter the fake code signing on Xcode 4.2

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Alright, after a lot of testing and digging up the filesystem... I solved it.
It turns out that there are just a few files that are not downloaded from the device (for reasons still unknown). They are related to the dyld cache (don't really know what this is and what it's for). Here are the steps to make your 4.2.1 device debuggable in XCode 4.2 and 4.3.x:

1. Close Xcode
2. Go to: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/` 
   *Note: if you don't have this folder, run Xcode, connect your device, and wait until the error 0xC002 appears in Organizer - the folder should be created by that time.*
3. Create 3 empty files there called:

   - `.copied_dyld_shared_cache_armv6`
   - `.processed_dyld_shared_cache_armv6`
   - `dyld_shared_cache_armv6`
4. Run Xcode and enjoy the light next to your device eventually go green:)

Or, for the terminal lovers:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/4.2.1\ \(8C148\)/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/
touch .copied_dyld_shared_cache_armv6
touch .processed_dyld_shared_cache_armv6
touch dyld_shared_cache_armv6
```

This is obviously a hack but it works perfectly for debugging and I haven't noticed any side-effects so far.

Enjoy!

Small update: 
 
I tested it on my snow leopard hackintosh, with the Xcode 4.2 (most recent to date) and although the device is active in the organizer and it is possible to run the app on the device, i get black screen on launch. It gets installed but apparently debugger cannot get attached. I had the same problem with 4.0.2, when the 0xC002 problem didn't yet occur so I think it's unrelated and might even not happen to others. Nevertheless, 0xC002 is still solved. 
On my main development machine with Lion and Xcode 4.3.2, device is perfectly debuggable.

Comment: I can't test it right now (my 3G is at home); but I'm marking this as the correct answer for now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I would be really glad to hear from you as soon as you test it, because this is my first Stackoverflow response and I'd like it to be at least correct :)

Comment: Worked for me using xcode 4.4.1 with a iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1

Comment: Worked for XCode 4.6 (4H127) with an iPod Touch 4G running iOS 6.0. Thanks!

Comment: @BartekEborn thank you for your solution. But I'm using Xcode 5.0 (5A1413) and iPhone 3GS with iOS version 6.0.1(10A523). And appeared such error in Organizer. Can you give solution for this situation. Or it is same for all kind of iPhone and Xcode? thanks.

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov Have you tried yourself first? I have neither 3GS nor XCode or even a Mac somewhere near now. As you see, people in comments were testing it using different Xcode/iOS/iPhone combinations and usually it worked. I don't follow recent changes but I guess Apple might have dropped support for 6.0.1 in XCode 5.0, so analogically, I would try in Step 2 going to:
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.0.1 (10A523)/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/
and proceeding with the other steps, obviously creating files with armv7 at the end instead of armv6 in step 3.

Comment: Oh, Bro I solved my problem :). By connecting another not jailbroken iPhone. When I connected second one. There created some folders in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.0.1 (10A523)/Symbols/System/Library/ and one file(dyld_shared_cache_armv7) in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.0.1 (10A523)/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/. Then I connected my problematic iPhone and it worked :)

Comment: Unbelievable that this is still working in year 2020!

Answer (score 7):

The answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9944892/1390251) works, basically,
but for newer versions of Xcode you probably need to rename the files as follows,
having them end with '7' instead of '6':

```
touch .copied_dyld_shared_cache_armv7
touch .processed_dyld_shared_cache_armv7
touch dyld_shared_cache_armv7
```

If not sure, you can keep both sets of files (...6 and ...7)
in the relevant folder (can also be 5.1.1 for that matter) 
and it should work.
(have tested it on iPhone 4 with iOS v5.1.1 genuine)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you cannot debug apps on iOS 4.2.1. I tried several restores to iOS 4.2.1 with same effect. Downgrading to iOS 4.0 was the only thing that worked.

The reason for whole problem is that iOS 4.2.1 is not supported in XCode, according to [this website](http://www.mactechnews.de/forum/thread/Xcode-4-2-Fehlermeldung-%5DXcode-has-encountered-an-unexpected-error-%280xC002%29-302998.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Error in Xcode getting debugging info from 5.0.1 iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114467/error-in-xcode-getting-debugging-info-from-5-0-1-iphone)
solved, see the link to archive with iOS5.0.1 debug info
download & unpack to "~/Library/Developer/xCode/iOS DeviceSupport/" & be happy =)

Comment: This sound promising, but our problem is with iOS 4.2.1 on a jailbroken iPhone 3G. Will perform some tests if/when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug in![enter image description here][1] this way:

I duplicate the 5.1.1(9B206), rename it to 5.1.1(9A405)[my ios device is this version], then the error is gone.