# Unable To Read Symbols Error In Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, symbols, debug-symbols

I am using the latest version of Xcode(4.2.1) and out of the blue, when I try to run my code on my device, the following flurry of text appears on the console:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/ahanmalhotra/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader (file not found).

warning: No copy of AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/ahanmalhotra/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/UIKit.axbundle/UIKit (file not found).

warning: No copy of UIKit.axbundle/UIKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/ahanmalhotra/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/TelephonyUIFramework.axbundle/TelephonyUIFramework (file not found).

warning: No copy of TelephonyUIFramework.axbundle/TelephonyUIFramework found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/ahanmalhotra/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 
(9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AXExtraExtras.axbundle/AXExtraExtras (file not found).

warning: No copy of AXExtraExtras.axbundle/AXExtraExtras found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

After this appears, my app starts normally and works. I am using an iPhone 4S running iOS 5.0.1. I have checked and "Generate Debug Symbols" is set to yes.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: When you run other apps on this simulator, do you get similar warnings for all of them?

Comment: @KineticStack, When I run other apps, the same warnings occur.

Comment: Note: Have tried reinstall of Xcode, did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found is that I needed to turn off Accessibility completely on the device. That means in Settings > General > Accessibility everything must be Off, including Triple-Click Home.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are you're missing some files.  Check out this [StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114467/error-in-xcode-getting-debugging-info-from-5-0-1-iphone).  It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I tried was to copy over the missing files from

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A334)/Symbols/System/Library

However you then get a warning about "UUID mismatch detected" for those same libraries. Not sure if there is much gained by doing so.