# How to use iOS 13.2.3 with Xcode 10.3 (dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13, xcode10

There is many answer about dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failure. Notably [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922308/xcode-4-2-error-0xc002-when-trying-to-use-a-jailbroken-iphone-3g-for-developmen/9944892#9944892) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539353/dyld-shared-cache-extract-dylibs-failed-for-6s-plus-running-on-ios-13-1-3) and this [github issue](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/issues/79).

None of this worked for me. I have the last iOS DeviceSupport installed, and I tried to remove the `dyld_shared_cache_arm64e` files, add empty `dyld_shared_cache_armv6` or `dyld_shared_cache_arm64e` files without success. Is it a way to use my phone without downgrading to iOS `13.1.2` ?

Answer (score 9):

I have Xcode 10.2.1 and iPhone 11 (iOS 13.3).

For iOS 13.3 Above solution not work because for iOS 13.3 not generate file like

"dyld_shared_cache_arm64"

It will generate file name like "dyld_shared_cache_arm64e" so copy this file from any iOS less then 13.3

I have copy "dyld_shared_cache_arm64" this file from "13.2 (17B84)" and past that file in "13.3 (17C54) arm64e" and rename this "dyld_shared_cache_arm64" to "dyld_shared_cache_arm64e"

and it successfully worked for me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show how to go to the above folders if I don’t display the Libraries

Comment: @JiosDev: Finder>Go>GoToFolder
"~/Library" keep this string and press Go

Comment: @bhavik: Thank you so much, finaly your solution works for me.
In addition I quite the XCode and started again then it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

By desperation I tried to replace my `iOS DeviceSupport/13.2.3 (17B111) arm64e/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld` files by the ones from `13.1.2 (17A861)`.

It was a huge success. Everything works again.

---

The command line I used to replace this files is:

```
cp "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/13.1.2 (17A861) arm64e/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_arm64e" "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/13.2.3 (17B111) arm64e/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/"
```

You have to replace `username` by your username, and look for your last available `dyld_shared_cache_arm64e` file.

I suspect this fix could works for any version of XCode.

Comment: Instead of replacing you better create a symbolic link to these support files under existing Xcode.app package

Comment: Could you tell me which files you are talking about? I actually don't know how this files are generated by XCode when you plug your phone. If they are distributed as part as developper tools, that would allow me to improve this answer :)
And by the way, since XCode create and write this file when you plug your phone, I prefer not to link it to any existent file. Just to be sure the original don't get modified.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Xcode and connect your device and go to the path

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport

2. And delete what ever version is corrupted.
3. Xcode will start creating it from the scratch

After successfully creating a whole folder by Xcode itself you can run any application on your device again.