# Xcode 10.1 dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed iOS 13.4

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, macos-mojave, ios13.4

I am trying to run iOS app on iPhone Xr (iOS 13.4) from Xcode 10.1 on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 
 version. But I get error

> dyld_shared_cache_extract_dylibs failed

I downloaded support file for 13.4 from [here](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport/blob/master/13.4.zip)

I have tried all the solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58971725/3883040), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4770751/3883040) and [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108917)

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this fixed by downloading a new Xcode 10.1 and then added 13.4 support file in Xcode.

**UPDATE**

Updated my iPhone to iOS 13.4.1 and started getting same error again. Then tried running app from Xcode 11 and was able to run app from there.

Then again tried running from Xcode 10.1 and it worked.